# Researchers and universities are to Academia as covert operatives and secret compounds are to...?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

The domain or the world of academics - teachers and researchers in universities and colleges - is referred to as academia. What do you call the domain of secret agents, spies and covert ops teams, with secure and secret compounds, under-the-radar government sections and the like?

**Note:** If possible, a term with a Latin flavor would be nice.

Comment: Maybe Intelligence?

Comment: In the US:  `Intelligence` is the "I" in CIA, DIA, etc.

Comment: Certainly not ***intelligensia**!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Espionage** would seem to be the best fit, I think.

merriam-webster.com:

> the practice of spying or using spies to obtain information about the plans and activities especially of a foreign government or a competing company

Comment: I agree. And [here's some supporting evidence](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=world+of+espionage%2Cworld+of+intelligence&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cworld%20of%20espionage%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworld%20of%20intelligence%3B%2Cc0) suggesting that *as a domain*, ***espionage*** has overtaken ***intelligence*** in recent decades.